# Is there a way to make Swift for loop use a variable outside the loop's scope as the loop counter?

Tags: swift

Is there a way to refer to a variable outside the `for` loop?

For instance

```
var output = ""

var data = ["a", "b", "c"]

let size = data.count
var i = 0

//
// How can I make this loop referring to variable "var i = 0"?
//
for i in 0..<size-1 {
    output.append(data[i])
    output.append("\n")
}

//
// Will not be executed because i remains 0
//
if (i == size-1) {
    output.append(data[i])
}
```

---

The only workaround I have found is

```
var output = ""

var data = ["a", "b", "c"]

let size = data.count
var i = 0

while (i < size-1) {
    output.append(data[i])
    output.append("\n")
    i = i + 1
}

if (i == size-1) {
    output.append(data[i])
}
```

Comment: You can't, what you have done here is called "shadowing" so your second variable shadows the one declared in the outer scope when you are inside the `for` loop

Comment: Are you trying to not adding an end line after the last value?

Comment: In your case, You can join the data array using \n

Comment: “ 0..<size-1” this crashes when size = 0. I think you would benefit from reading https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md#for-i-in-0arraycount-1--

Comment: Did you know there’s a built in function for this, which removes the need for you to tinker around with loops and stuff? Just  `let output = data.joined(separator: “\n”)`

Comment: Yes. I am aware of the built-in join function. The actual code is more complicate than this. I just illustrate a simple "join" operation by using for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep roughly the same syntax by using a different variable name within the `for` loop and then assigning it to the outer variable.
In your example, naming the variable `i` will shadow the outer variable (as mentioned in the comments) within the scope of the `for` loop, making the outer variable inaccessible in the scope of the `for` loop.

There's currently no syntax in Swift to force a `for` loop's current value to bind to an existing variable.

```swift
var output = ""

var data = ["a", "b", "c"]

let size = data.count
var i = 0

for j in 0..<size-1 {
    i = j
    output.append(data[i])
    output.append("\n")
}

if (i == size-1) {
    output.append(data[i])
}
```

Comment: If the array.count is 1000+ or data[i] is an image or something like this then the if statement will execute before completing the for loop. In this case, i will be less than (size -1) while checking the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use built-in function then you can check where it is less than the last index. As-

```
for i in 0..<size-1 {
    output.append(data[i])
    if i < size-1 {
        output.append("\n")
    }
}
```